# Timsort implementation in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, sorting, timsort

I wanted to implement a [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) in python.

Here's what I've come up with:

```
from typing import List

RUN = 32

def insertionSort(unsorted: List[int], left: int, right: int) -> None:
    """ Sorts the array using insertion sort """

    for i in range(left + 1, right + 1):
        temp = unsorted[i]
        j = i-1

        while unsorted[j] > temp and j >= left:
            unsorted[j+1] = unsorted[j]
            j -= 1

        unsorted[j+1] = temp

def merge(unsorted: List[int], left: int, middle: int, right: int) -> None:
    """ Merges two sorted arrays """

    len1 = middle - left + 1
    len2 = right - middle

    left_side  = unsorted[left : left + len1]
    right_side = unsorted[middle + 1 : middle + len2 + 1]

    i = j = 0
    k = left

    while i < len1 and j < len2:
        if left_side[i] <= right_side[j]:
            unsorted[k] = left_side[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            unsorted[k] = right_side[j]
            j += 1

        k += 1

    while i < len1:
        unsorted[k] = left_side[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1

    while j < len2:
        unsorted[k] = right_side[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1

def timSort(unsorted: List[int], length: int) -> None:
    """

    Sorts every 'RUN' elements by insertion sort as
            insertion sort is faster for smaller array lengths

    """

    # Sorts every RUN elements using insertion sort
    for i in range(0, length, RUN):
        insertionSort(unsorted, i, min(i + 31, length - 1))

    size = RUN

    # Merges every sorted subarray using Merge Sort
    while size < length:
        left = 0

        while left < length:
            mid = min(left + size - 1, length - 1)
            right = min(left + 2 * size - 1, length - 1)

            merge(unsorted, left, mid, right)

            left += size * 2

        size *= 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unsorted = list(map(int, input('Enter space seperated elements: ').split()))
    n = len(unsorted)

    timSort(unsorted, n)

    print('Here\'s the sorted array: ')
    print(*unsorted)
```

I think it looks good, but I want to make it even better.

PS: What would be the optimal length for `RUN`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to implement Timsort in Python is of course to use the built-in version:

```
def timsort(x):
    return sorted(x)
```

Since you don't learn anything from that, implementing it yourself is of course nice.

First, some general comments.

- Python has an official style-guide, PEP8. It recommends using `lower_case` for variables and functions. It also recommends using empty lines sparingly.
- You don't need to pass the length to the algorithm. Every indexable Python object has a length, so just use `len(unsorted)`.
- Your type hints say that this function can only take lists of integers. It works perfectly fine with lists of any comparable type, just like the built-in `sorted`.
- Choosing to modify the input list in-place is perfectly fine for lists (after all, `list.sort` does the same thing). But if you do that, it should be noted in the `docstring`. You could, however, also choose to conform closer to `sorted` and first copy the iterable into a list (simply copying if it already is a list), sorting it in-place and returning it. This would change the signature to `tim_sort(x: Iterable[Any]) -> List[Any]`.
- The built-in sorting functions all take a `key` argument, which is called once per argument. This results in effectively sorting `[key(element) for element in x]` and afterwards returning only the second element from each inner tuple.

Now, let's take a closer look at your actual code.

You use `while` loops quite a lot. While (pun intended) they almost always work, they are not always the most efficient (in readability) way to accomplish your goal. In the `merge` function you can replace the last two `while` loops with list slice assignments. I would also simplify the setting of `left_side` and `right_side` by using `left`, `middle` and `right` instead of `left`, `middle`, `len1` and `len2`.

```
def merge(unsorted: List[int], left: int, middle: int, right: int) -> None:
    """ Merges two sorted arrays """
    len1 = middle - left + 1
    len2 = right - middle
    left_side  = unsorted[left:middle + 1]
    right_side = unsorted[middle + 1:right + 1]
    
    i = j = 0
    k = left
    while i < len1 and j < len2:
        if left_side[i] <= right_side[j]:
            unsorted[k] = left_side[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            unsorted[k] = right_side[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1

    unsorted[k:] = left_side[i:]
    unsorted[k + len1 - i:] = right_side[j:]
```

Instead of slices, you can also create a new list and use `extend`:

```
def merge(unsorted: List[int], left: int, middle: int, right: int) -> None:
    """ Merges two sorted arrays """
    len1 = middle - left + 1
    len2 = right - middle
    left_side  = unsorted[left:middle + 1]
    right_side = unsorted[middle + 1:right + 1]
    
    i = j = 0
    k = left
    out = []
    while i < len1 and j < len2:
        if left_side[i] <= right_side[j]:
            out.append(left_side[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            out.append(right_side[j])
            j += 1
        k += 1
    out.extend(left_side[i:])
    out.extend(right_side[j:])
    unsorted[:] = out
```

The first `while` loop could also use iterators instead of indices, but that is left as an exercise for now.

Comment: That's not the easiest way, easiest way is `timsort = sorted` :-P (then you even get its parameters for free)

Comment: @superbrain: I would argue that "The easiest way to implement Timsort in Python is of course to use the built-in version" is still true, but I did not give the simplest possible implementation of that :D And you are right, getting the options for free without having to do `*args, **kwargs` is nice.

Comment: `[(key(element), element) for element in x]` isn't quite right, since the element itself is *not* used in the comparisons then, only the key is. More seriously: Your merge functions don't work, cause `TypeError: 'list_iterator' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: Plus your first `merge` would remove everything right of `right` and your second `merge` would also remove everything left of `left`. The slice assignments need to take those bounds into account.

Comment: @superbrain: Looks like somebody didn't test their code...I'll see if I can fix it up.

Comment: Maybe you did test, but only with an input shorter than `RUN`, in which case `merge` is never used.

Comment: The updated versions both cause IndexError for example on `unsorted = [13] * 666`.